# ModuleNotFoundError or what is wrong with this language

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my simple project. When I try to run app.py I got an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "worker/app.py", line 4, in <module>
    from worker import app_config
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'worker'
```

[image]

Here is content of app.py

```
import logging
from logging import config

from worker import app_config
from worker import controller

config.dictConfig(app_config.LOGGING)
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def start():
    log.info("Worker started")
    controller.update_whats_new()
    log.info("Worker exit")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start()
```

**init**.py is empty, PYTHONPATH env is empty too

Comment: please check and share your pythonpath env variable and __init__.py file contents

Comment: Just `import app_config` should be fine since they're in the same folder.

Comment: @PriyankMehta both empty